# How to add point to stroke from grease pencil

Tags: grease-pencil

I know its a simple question, but I didnt find it anywhere. I dont know how to make point in stroke from grease pencil between two points.
[image]

Ive tried it with *Ctrl+J*. I duplicated line and joined it, but its slow and I think Blender has better solution to do it.